# converting digits in ASCII characters gives segmentation fault in Assembler (nasm)

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm new to this forum, so please forgive me for obvious mistakes. I'm trying to write a code that converts the single digits of a machine number in ASCII characters with base 10. My strategy is to convert them first by division and putting the remainder in an array and print that array aftwerwards.

I've been working on it the whole day and I can't wrap my head around it. When I'm running the code I get a segmentation fault, except when I choose a number that is divisible by 10 in one go. E.g 10000, 200 or 500. P.s. the numbers are printed in the wrong order, but that must be relatively easy to solve.

Here is the info from the compiler:

nasm -f elf32 division.asm

ld -m elf_i386 -s -o division division.o

Here is the code

```
section .text

global _start

_start:


mov     dword [arrvar], digit
mov     eax, [value]
call    convert

mov     dword [arrvar], digit
call    printarray

mov     eax, 1
int     80h


convert:
 mov    ebx, 10
 div    ebx

 push   edx
 add    edx, '0'

 mov    ecx, [arrvar]
 mov    [ecx], edx
 add    dword [arrvar], 4
 inc    byte [elements]
 pop    edx

 cmp    eax, 0
 jne    convert
 ret

printarray:
    mov     ecx, [arrvar]
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     edx, 1
    int     80h
    add     dword [arrvar], 4
    dec     byte [elements]
    cmp     byte [elements], 0
    jne     printarray
    mov     eax, 4
    mov     ecx, newl
    mov     edx, 1
    mov     ebx, 1
    int     80h
    ret



 mov    eax, 1
 int    80h

section .data

 newl   db 10

 value dd 1000500000

 elements db 0

section .bss

 arrvar resb 4

 digit resd 100
```

Comment: As usual, you forgot to zero `edx` before division. Read how the `div` instruction works, and also learn to use a debugger.

Comment: yes, that did the trick! Thanks for your tip about the debugger. I'll try to install one right now. If you've any suggestions for sublime text editor that would be great, because for newbies there are so many options and I don't know what's worth to spend time on.